# Why are Canon DSLRs relatively more expensive than Nikon DSLRs?

Tags: canon, nikon, camera-recommendation

When I [snapsort compare](http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-EOS-760D-vs-Nikon-D5500) the Nikon D5500 and the Canon 760D, the Nikon is far better spec-wise, but the 760D is more expensive. Are there any specs that are unknown to me that are better in the Canon which makes the Canon more expensive?

Comment: Could you add details as to what you think makes the Nikon "far better"?

Comment: Snapsort has a bigger number! 92 is _clearly_ far better than 70. And if you look at the details, Snapsort says that the D5500 has "20% better image quality". This is objectively and abjectly ridiculous, but it's completely understandable that people are mislead.

Comment: @Caleb The first version of this question did indeed relate "compare" to the comparison on Snapsort (by way of a hyperlink)

Comment: @osullic You're right -- I remembered the original question, but didn't realize that 'compare' was a link.

Comment: You are not comparing similar models. Nikon does not have an intermediate DSLR with efficient controls and a light body. There is a T6i (750D?) which is comparable to the Nikon and then so, the numbers you get from generated comparisons like that are meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

Specs aren't everything.

The Canon 760D has a number of usability features the D5500 doesn't.

- Two-wheel controls (easier to operate than a single-wheel model)
- A top LCD
- true mirror lock-up
- DOF preview button
- high-speed sync flash capability (called FP in Nikon terminology) with an external flash
- wireless flash master/commander built-in
- autofocus with any current Canon dSLR lens (D5500 can only autofocus with Nikon's AF-S lenses.)

Since some of these features actually do require additional hardware, that probably explains the "premium" for the Canon body.  A more direct equivalent to the D5500 is probably the 750D/T6i.

Comment: There are also subjective specs, like ergonomics. Holding a camera in your hand is something no datasheet can tell. And by all means, you should hold it in your hand before buying! Rent the cameras and try it out. | Then there's user interface in general: button layout, menus, etc. All this could favour the Nikon or Canon camera (not depending on any datasheet, but your personal opinion), but if you like the Canon one more, this is also what could make the extra money worth it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are some features in the 760D that are overlooked in your comparison:

1) top LCD screen 
2) individual dials for Aperture and Shutter speed
3) larger buffer that allows you to take more photos in a fast burst
4) better autofocus in Video and Liveview

The 760D is only about $100 more than the D5500. Price wise, the direct competition for D5500 would be the Canon 750DD which lacks the top LCD and rear "Quick Control Dial". They are both about $750.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the cost might reflect the customer support given by Canon, or in other words the support network behind the product. I know first hand that Canon support is quite good compared to what I have read and heard about from Nikon eg the dirty sensor on one of their new camera models awhile back. Also comments by Roger Cicala at Lens Rentals about his experience with after sales service offered by Nikon. I reckon this aspect of the purchase shouldn't be underestimated.

Comment: You're right -- customer service is an important consideration, and Canon's has been very good in my experience.